# Android - How to stop images reloading in Recyclerview when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was creating an app for loading images from internet in cards. I am using Recyclerview for listing purpose. For downloading images, I have tried Picasso, universal-image-downloader and other custom methods but everywhere I have this problem:

Whenever I scroll down and up the images in imageview are getting reloaded. I have even kept a condition to check if the imageview contains an image but that also doesn't seem to work or my code may be faulty. But I am not able to find a solution to this problem. Below I have attached the 'onBindViewHolder' function of my code which I think is the problematic part. Here images is a string arraylist containing image urls.

```java
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {            
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.default_card, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {            
        String url = images.get(position);

        if (holder.imgView.getDrawable() != null) {
            //Do Nothing
        } else {                
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.imgView);               
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Whenever I scroll down and up the images in imageview are getting reloaded" -- what does this mean? "or my code may be faulty" -- yes, it is faulty. It nevers bind a new image to this `ImageView` when the `ViewHolder` is recycled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, there is a bug in your code - you have to remove the condition from `onBindViewHolder`. All `ImageView` instances has to be updated each time they are about to display.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {            
    String url = images.get(position);               
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.imgView);               
}
```

**The reloading part**:

The problem is, that you are probably not using any cache (in-memory, or disk based). I would not elabarote on this a lot, caching of images in collection views is a really common problem and I'm sure a quick StackOverflow search will give you a lot of results.

Just in particular - Universal image [does not have caching enabled by default](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) You can turn it on this way.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    ...
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    ...
    .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options); // Incoming options will be used
```

Or you can set it globally for your application, just check the docs.

Comment: I have set the cacheInMemory and cacheInDisk options already. I don't know why it didn't work before but removing the condition did the trick but still I can see when I scroll down some new images are changing but only a few.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.fit()` with Picasso. Hope that solves your problem

```
Picasso.with(persons.get(i).context)
    .load(persons.get(i).photoId)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .fit()
    .into(personPhoto);
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much, i search too much and wast time on this error, but this your litte answer help me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to solve your issue.

```
mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Cache, you can use setItemViewCacheSize(size) and mention the size where you don't want to reload. That's it. Recyclerview version 24.0.0